# Python - Error when trying to add comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am learning about reading/writing strings, lists, etc to txt/dat files.  I wanted to add a comment in my code so I can refer back to what the access keys are.  So this is what I did.

```
# Mode   Description
# rb     Read from a binary file. If the file doesn’t exist, Python will complain with an error.
# wb     Write to a binary file. If the file exists, its contents are overwritten. If the file doesn’t exist,
#        it’s created.
# ab     Append a binary file. If the file exists, new data is appended to it. If the file doesn’t exist, it’s
#        created.
# rb+    Read from and write to a binary file. If the file doesn’t exist, Python will complain with an
#        error.
# wb+    Write to and read from a binary file. If the file exists, its contents are overwritten. If the file
#        doesn’t exist, it’s created.
# ab+    Append and read from a binary file.
```

And after I have:

```
import pickle, shelve

print("Pickling lists.")
variety = ["sweet", "hot", "dill"]
shape = ["whole", "spear", "chip"]
brand = ["Claussen", "Heinz", "Vlassic"]

f = open("pickles1.dat", "wb")

pickle.dump(variety, f)
pickle.dump(shape, f)
pickle.dump(brand, f)
f.close()

print("\nUnpickling lists.")
f = open("pickles1.dat", "rb")
variety = pickle.load(f)
shape = pickle.load(f)
brand = pickle.load(f)

print(variety)
print(shape)
print(brand)
f.close()
```

When I run it I get the following error:

SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x92' in file PickleIt.py on line 10, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

I checked out the link, but I really don't understand it, I haven't seen this before.

---

Oh and apologies **line 10 is `# rb`**

Comment: remove the `apostrophes` in comment and then try again

Comment: Wow, that fixed it, thank you.  I deleted and replaced them.  Does that mean that python or the ide didn't recognize the ' that I had copied over?

Comment: it is not `utf-8` supported char, i think it is `ascii` or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace all the `’` by `'`.
It's complaining because you didn't add the encoding type to the beginning of the file. The default encoding is `utf-8`, in which those characters are not allowed.

Instead of replacing, you can add this line to the beginning (before the comments):

`# coding: iso-8859-1`

(Or another encoding in which those characters are present, like `latin-1` for example.)

This line sets the encoding for the file and allows the use of special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the smart quotes `’` with the regular quote `'` in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

this character seems to be the problem ’